# How to do CameraUpdate for more than 2 locations in Google Maps Android API v2?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to show more than one markers in google map and show them in single view. I've shown all markers on map but I'm struggling with CameraUpdate. Please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a LatLngBounds:

```
List<Marker> myMarkers; //your list of markers
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
for(Marker m: myMarkers){
    builder.include(m.getPosition());
}
LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 20);//20 is padding, use it to avoid markers on the border of the map view
mMap.animateCamera(cu);
```